# Swift: Second animation not running

Tags: ios, swift

The code below is designed to make a UIButton bounce up and down, but the second animation never appears to run.

Any suggestions?

```
// Set animation properties
let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction
let originalY = saveButton.center.y
let originalX = saveButton.center.x
let bounceDelta = CGFloat(5)

// Run animation
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: options, animations: {
    self.saveButton.center = CGPoint(x: originalX, y: originalY - bounceDelta)
    }, completion: { finished in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: options, animations: {
            self.saveButton.center = CGPoint(x: originalX, y: originalY + bounceDelta)
        }, completion: nil)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using 'Autoreverse' on both of your animations.

Try using CAKeyframeAnimation instead. There is a block based api for it on UIView these days.

http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/04/01/stop-nesting-animation-blocks/

Comment: Thanks, does CAKeyframeAnimation allow you to stop the animation?

Comment: Yes. Use it's delegate callback and call 'removeAllAnimations' on your layer.